# Python: изменение двумерного списка в цикле

Tags: python, list

Столкнулся с странной особенностью двумерных списков.

```
ll = [['']*5]*5

for i in range(0, 5):
    for j in range(0, 5):
        if (i==j) :
            print('yes', i, j)
            ll[i][j] = 'yes'
        if (i!=j):
            print('no', i, j)
            ll[i][j] = 'no'
#ожидаю получить строку 'yes', но получаю 'no'
ll[0][0]
#здесь получаю строку 'no'
ll[0][1]
```

Как объяснить такой результат?

Comment: Распечатайте весь список -- он состоит из одинаковых подсписков. Также можно воспользоваться отладчиком, чтобы увидеть динамику изменений

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вы создаёте список, а потом умножаете его на 5, таким образом он не клонируется, а копируется сам объект со всеми его адресамм

поэтому надо место `ll = [[''] * 5] * 5` писать `ll = [[''] * 5 for _ in range(5)]`